# Default video player for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vlc

How do I make VLC my default video player on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to Settings (which can be selected through Activities window, and typing 'settings' in the input bar)
2. Select 'Default Applications' in the left task bar.
3. In the 'Video' dropdown menu, select 'VLC media player'.

   [image: See the image here !]

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS system, Default Applications just isn't visible in the Settings window left menu, not sure why.  But clicking the Search button (magnifying glass top left) ad searching for "Default" found it.